# How to get php vars to display in html

Tags: php, html

I am executing a php script which collects some variables from a form, then displays a page from a MySQL table. The page is displayed fine, but the echoed variable are not.

```
    <h4>Conference Registration</h4>
    <p><strong>
        <?php echo $confName $confDate; ?>
    </strong></p>
```

The expected result is that the two variable are displayed.
I tested that the variable were available by inserting an echo command at the top of the page.

The actual result is that the variable are not displayed.

When displaying the page source in the browser and hovering over the `<?php` line displayed in red, the following is displayed:

> Saw "`<p`". Probable cause: Attempt to use an XML processing
>   instruction in HTML. (XML procesing instructions are not supported in
>   HTML.)

Comment: When viewing the source of a PHP page you should never see the actual PHP like `<?php` unless you're on a server that isn't configure to use PHP or if you're opening the page locally.

Comment: I think it's more down to syntax error: `<?php echo $confName $confDate; ?>`

Comment: Even a syntax error would not show `<?php` in the browser source.

Comment: point. could @neholtz try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1; error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script please?

Comment: @treyBake: Missing right paren on your second line. Was `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1; Should be `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);  No changes. php code still shows in browser source. Server is shared hosting on HM.

Comment: This is for one form receiving some `$_POST variables` from the submission of another form.
Before the <!doctype tag of the receiving form there is php code which retrieves the `$_POST variables` submitted by the first form.
Those `$_POST variables` ARE there. Verified by `echo str_replace('  ', '&nbsp; ', nl2br(print_r($_POST, true)));` and also by echoing local variables which were populated from the `$_POST variables`.
The code in the html page to display them is: `<?php echo $confName; ?>`, but the data still does not show up on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot just place two variables next to each other and expect the `echo` command to display them. You need to use two `echo` commands, or place a comma between the variables:

```
echo $confName;
echo $confDate;

// or use comma;
echo $confName, $confDate;
```

Or alternatively, learn how to [concatenate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php) the variables:

```
echo $confName." - ".$confDate;
```

Comment: my linked dupe resolves it ^^ no need to add an answer (if it turns out that's the crux of the issue)

Comment: I tried the `<?php echo  $confName." - ".$confDate; ?>
The php still shows up in the browser page source.

Comment: So your issue is that the PHP code is physically showing in your browser? Is your page using the `.php` extension? Is your webserver configured and running properly?

Answer (score 2):

echo takes in a string or a list of strings [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php)

echo can accept

- ($confName, $confDate) *(handles as a list)*
- $confName, $confDate *(handles as a list)*
- $confName . $confDate *(handles as a single string since it is concatenated)*

so something like

```
<h4>Conference Registration</h4>
  <p><strong>
    <?php echo $confName, $confDate; ?>
  </strong></p>
```

or I would recommend using using `<?=*var* ?>` since it looks cleaner

As Tom Scholz mentioned, if you are on a PHP version older then **5.4.0** you must set `short_open_tag=on` in your php.ini file

```
<h4>Conference Registration</h4>
  <p><strong>
    <?=$confName.$confDate ?>
  </strong></p>
```

Comment: `<?=` doesn't always work, since prior to php 5.4 it was disabled by default. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

Comment: @TomScholz Yes but that is a quick fix in the php.ini: `short_open_tag=on` for anyone on the older versions. The odds are slim from the question that he is running an older version like that.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that it *could* be a problem :) Lots of folks are (unfortunately) still running on old php versions.

Comment: your first bullet will give a syntax error, the manual says explicit: "Additionally, if you want to pass more than one parameter to echo, the parameters **must not** be enclosed within parentheses."

Answer (score 0):

Use the **concatenation operator** **`.`**

```
<?php echo $confName.$confDate; ?>
```